# Finding $\lim_{x\to0}\int_0^1\frac{xf(t)}{x^2+t^2}\,dt$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, limits, definite-integrals, limits-without-lhopital

> Let $f$ be a continuous function and $f:[0,1]\to\mathbb R$. Find $$\lim_{x\to0}\int_0^1\frac{xf(t)}{x^2+t^2}\,dt$$

I am finding that the limit does not exist. But the question is *stated* in a way to enable one to think that the limit actually *exists*. But I don't think the limit exists, the reason being simple:

> By Mean Value Theorem we can write the integral as $$xf(c)\int_0^1\frac{dt}{x^2+t^2}=f(c)\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$$
>
> Consider a positive subsequence of $x_n\to0$ for which $f(c)\tan^{-1}(\frac{1}{x})\to f(c)\frac{\pi}{2}$ and for a negative subsequence of $x_n\to0$ we will have $f(c)\tan^{-1}(\frac{1}{x})\to-f(c)\frac{\pi}{2}$. So the limit does not exist.

So is it a situation of mis-statement of a question or am I doing something wrong?

EDIT: I forgot to mention that in my solution, $c\in(0,1)$

Comment: Maybe cases must be considered. Notice that $c=c_x$ depends on $x$ and that maybe $f$ vanishes somewhere and $c_{x_n}$ tends to that point. Do we have more information about $f$? For example, does $\int_{0}^{1}\frac{f(t)}{t^2}$ exist?

Comment: Yes you are correct that $c=c_x$ and I realized that after posting the problem. But even then, the limit seems to be simply $\lim_{x\to0}f(c_x)\tan^{-1}(\dfrac{1}{x})$ and then?And no, we have no other information about $f$.

Comment: Well, your argument is good for when $f$ never vanishes. On the other hand, when $\int_{0}^{1}\frac{f}{t^2}$ does exists (in particular $f(0)=0$) then the limit is zero.

Comment: @Pp.. can you kindly explain why your special case will allow the limit as given in the problem, be zero? I mean, why do you claim that if it was given that $\int_0^1\dfrac{fdt}{t^2}$ was finite and $f(0)=0$ then the limit mentioned in question would be $0$?

Comment: Why should $c$ depend on $x$?

Comment: @Ahmed Hussain, because the integral depends on $x$. Once you vary $x$, the value of the integral varies, in particular $f(c)$ varies.

Comment: @yedaynara The factor $|\int_{0}^{1}\frac{f}{x^2+t^2}|\leq\int_{0}^{1}\frac{|f|}{t^2}$ would be bounded and the other factor $x$ tends to zero.

Comment: Pp.. Thank you for the nice observation!! But no other condition being given, apart from what is stated in the question, what do you think?

Comment: @yedaynara this isn't true. $x$ is just a variable multiplied by the function being integrated; the integration itself doesn't involve $x$. $x$ is a constant in the integration process. We are integrating with respect to $t$.

Comment: @Ahmed that is true, but please do not forget that the integration of $f(t)dt/(x^2+t^2)$ itself depends on $x$, now once you start varying $x$ while taking the limit, as $x\to0$, it is obvious that the $c$ obtained from MVT will change, as that was the $c$ obtained by integrating a function that depended on "one" $x$. Now that $x$ has changed, so my $c$ also should change!!

Comment: $c$ is just a constant in $]0,1[$, independent of the variables present. If the bound of integration contained $x$, then $c$ would be a function of $x$; but this is not the case. Your work is fine and the result is true, there is a limit - namely $f(c)\pi/2$.

Comment: It seems to me that the limit is zero for every polynomial $f$. Maybe one can use the density of polynomials in the space of continuous functions defined on $[0,1]$...

Comment: @Siminore: what about $f(t)=1$? In such a case the limits as $x\to 0^+$ and $x\to 0^-$ are different, as pointed by the OP.

Comment: To summarize, the limit is zero for every continuous function that vanishes at the origin. I tend to believe that the "author" of the question was thinking of the case $x>0$, since otherwise the answer would be trivial.

Answer (score 0):

Assume for the moment that $x>0$. Then the change of variable $t=xu$ turns the integral into
$$
\int_{[0,1/x]} \frac{f(xu)}{1+u^2}du.
$$
If $$d\mu = \frac{dx}{1+u^2},$$ then by the dominated convergence theorem with respect to the *finite* measure (so that constants are integrable!) $\mu$ shows that the last integral converges to $f(0)\mu (\mathbb{R}^+)$.

If $x \in \mathbb{R}$, the constant function $f =1$ shows that the limit does not exist.

Comment: Do you mean $d\mu=\frac{du}{1+u^2}$?